# Get all values of Kendo multiselect on selecting "ALL" Option

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-multiselect

```
var SelectedMapTypes = $("#msMapType").data("kendoMultiSelect")
```

This is my Kendo Multiselect.

i need to get all the multiselect values when i click ALL from the multiselect.

Please help.

Datasource : Populating from database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to *select* all values in the multiselect (when "All" selected), you can use:

```
select: function(e) {
    var dataItem = this.dataSource.view()[e.item.index()];

    var values = dataItem.value === "ALL" ? 
        $.map(this.dataSource.data(), function(dataItem) {
            return dataItem.value;
        }) 
        : this.value();

    this.value(values); // values holds all items within the multiselect

}
```

[Dojo Example](http://dojo.telerik.com/eDuQA)